# Page access tokens from web app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token

I'm writing a facebook web app with Graph API for publishing on a page wall automatically. I'm the page administrator and I've set up the app permissions for requiring manage_pages, offline_access, read_stream and publish_stream. My app will be like twitterfeed app with something different (I've no rss feed as a source).

For the first step I call:

`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=".$app_id."&client_secret=".$app_secret."&grant_type=client_credentials`

When this call return an access_token I call:

`https://graph.facebook.com/100344706779072?fields=access_token&access_token=". $access_token`

Here I have problems: as facebook doc says (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#page_access_tokens) I must get page_access_token in this way, but this call return only the page id..

So what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the facebook docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-page/

you need to use the access token you got in the first call and make a second call to https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=$access_token

and you'll get a reply that looks like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "PAGE_TITLE", 
      "access_token": "PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN", 
      "category": "PAGE_CATEGORY", 
      "id": "PAGE_ID"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "PAGE_TITLE", 
      "access_token": "PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN", 
      "category": "PAGE_CATEGORY", 
      "id": "PAGE_ID"
    }, 

    ...

 ]
}
```